# How to use Fastify strategies as AuthGuards with NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, fastify

Fastify has its own package to handle strategies, which is [`fastify-auth`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-auth). Among its strategies include [`fastify-basic-auth`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-basic-auth) and [`fastify-jwt`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-jwt).

NestJS has a wrapper for passport strategies; [`@nestjs/passport`](https://github.com/nestjs/passport), along with its [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication). I don't think they have a wrapper for Fastify strategies. I'm not sure how I would go about implementing the strategies into the project.

In the end, I would like to do the following:

```js
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('FastifyBasicAuth'))
@Post('login')
async login() {
    /* Logic... */
}
```